# Method/Task scheduler c#

Tags: c#

I'm using C#.
I think thats a noob question but i'm try anyway.
I have a C# project with methods: `X(),Y(),Z()`.

I'm looking for a task scheduler that run for me every day/every hour my methods (X(),Y(),Z()) at diffrent times.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Why not simply create a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Check Windows Task Scheduler of Quartz.net if you need a framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a console application that accepts a single parameter (think `myapp.exe x`) that would call respective function. Then add a number of scheduled tasks to Windows Scheduler and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use an existing library.  Scott Hanselman had a blog on this a while back http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx.

Note: the article mentions asp.net however the schedulers are mentioned can also be run through console or Windows apps.

I personally use the Fluent scheduler (https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) which has now been updated to support .net core.  It's easy to use, and if you have simple scheduling requirements probably the one I'd recommend.

Comment: The OP didn't specify a web application. A simple scheduled job would be more than enough and offers a lot more functionality (eg triggers). Fluent Scheduler or Quartz.NET would be appropriate for a windows service

Comment: I didn't say anything about a web application.  I actually use the Fluent scheduler through a continously running console app.  What the other have said about using windows task schedule is fine.  If you write scheduling into the program it's self, it means you can do more with regards to error handling and dependencies between jobs.  However all this may be overkill for OP's requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I've put a note in original answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run some code every hour, every day or any other clearly known period, then the best option is to create a console application and use Windows Task Scheduler to run this application.

If this period is unclear and depends on some logics or calculations, then the best option is using always-running Windows Services which will run your methods when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is always run, you can try with reactive extensions:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Subscribe(x=>X());
```

Check here for more infohttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would make a windows service, and in the windows service you can call your methods with a timer check. (we did it so in our old company)